# Python if condition after amount of time

Tags: python

I have a basic code with simple condition:

```
if var1 > 0 :   
   dosomething
```

how can I prolong the execution after the condition is true for few seconds? Something like:

```
if var > 0 ("after 5 seconds"):
   dosomething
```

Comment: This sounds like you are waiting for a special event. Maybe waiting is a working, but not good idea. What you want to reach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this ; `sleep(5)` will delay the program for 5 seconds:

```
import time 

x = 10
if x > 0:
    # if true 
    time.sleep(5)
else:
     #dosomething
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `time.sleep` at an appropriate place:

```
from time import sleep
sleep(5)  # will block for 5 seconds
```